# How to convert E+011 to number

Tags: php, function, numbers

`3.3099016081e+012` should be `3309901608149`

`1.0553402147e+011` should be `0105534021470`

`3.1004004826e+012` should be `3100400482588`

Comment: What do you mean, "solve"? It already is a number. Do you mean you want to display it without the `e` notation? `sprintf('%f', 3.3099016081e+012);` will give you `"3309901608100.000000"`. Use `%.0f` if you want to get rid of the `.0000` part.

Comment: you probably only miss a formating in your output. But as you don't share any code nor what things you tried... little to say here

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format(3.3099016081e+012,0,'','')
```

However, for working with large numbers, if you want to keep precision, you should look into [BCMath extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could display these correctly. Firstly you can increase the numeric `precision` assigned to floats in php or you can use `sprintf`.

```
<?php
    ini_set('precision',20);
    $bigint=33099016081494738093;
    echo $bigint;
    --> 33099016081494736896;

    or

    echo sprintf('%020.0f', $bigint);
    --> 33099016081494736896;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the right direction.

```
$var = 3.3099016081e+012;
echo number_format($var, 0 , '', '');
```

The output is 3309901608100 and also take a look at this [Floating point precision in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)